# In react-native how can I solve error setNativeProps is deprecated?

Tags: react-native

When I click on Text value.name modal is shown. That is correct, exactly like I want.

But in console, I have this error.

```
setNativeProps is deprecated. Please update props using React state instead.
```

My code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Button, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles";
import TextModal from "../Modal/TextModal";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

const Placeholders = (props) => {
    const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
    const [numberClicked, setNumberClicked] = useState(-1);

    const toggleModalVisibility = (index) => {
        console.log(index);
        setIsModalVisible(!isModalVisible);
        setNumberClicked(index);
    };

    const showEveryValue = () => {
        let values = [];
        let keyCounter = 0;
        props.values.forEach((value) => {
            values.push(
                <View
                    key={keyCounter++}
                >
                    <Text
                        onPress={() => toggleModalVisibility(value.number)}
                    >
                        {value.name}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            );
        });
        return values;
    };

    return (
        <>
            {showEveryValue()}
            <Modal
                isVisible={isModalVisible}
                style={styles.modal}
            >
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => toggleModalVisibility()}
                    style={styles.touchableOpacity}
                >
                    <TextModal
                        numberClicked={numberClicked}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
};

export default Placeholders;
```

How to solve this problem?

On [this page](https://medium.com/@david.zhao.blog/setnativeprops-is-deprecated-please-update-props-using-react-state-instead-7d5b17e4c197) I read that it is problem with react-native packages. Is it true? Or the error is somewhere in my code?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, according to  [your link](https://medium.com/@david.zhao.blog/setnativeprops-is-deprecated-please-update-props-using-react-state-instead-7d5b17e4c197):
As 2023–02–07, React Native team is working on this issue. There is no solution or workaround on this issue.